Keyboard navigation to "my profile"
Description
Inspired from Keyboard shortcut to go to profile page is broken. Currently keyboard navigation for visiting your own profile does not work.
This adds the necessary class in the document so when the keyboard shortcuts are enabled you can use G -> P to visit your profile
Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
(For instructions how to install userscripts: see the tag wiki here)
Code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Keyboard navigation to profile
// @description     Allow keyboard navigation to personal profile (G->P)
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://superuser.com/*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/*
// @version         1.0
// @author          VLAZ
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    const userProfile = document.querySelector("#user-profile-button img");

    if (!userProfile) {
        console.warn("Could not find a user profile on the page. The fix for keyboard navigation is not active.")
        return;
    }

    userProfile.classList.add("profile-me");
})();

